# generateCMake doesn't seem to generate all the files

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm trying to generate the libcurl example project from scratch with gradle to be able debug in CLion.

I get this error in CLion after using `gradle generateCMake`:

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineKotlinCompiler.cmake
```

The KotlinCMakeModule is empty.

Am I missing something ?
I can debug the demo project, but the project has been generated by the team.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is an intermediate approach to building Kotlin/Native code, suggested approach is to use Gradle, and proper tooling in IDE will be available very soon. Thus, we suggest not to rely on CMake, or invest time in playing with CMake files.

Comment: I was just trying to get autocompletion for cinterop which I wasn't able to get from build.gradle. This is a great news and I really hope the new IDE will solve the slow autocompletion problem. I will wait for monday to give it a try :-) Thank you for your answer.